# Index/Match to Return Multiple Values

Tags: excel, vba, formulas

I've successfuly used INDEX and MATCH, but I have a problem.

For example, if the data were:

```
green apple | walmart |  5 
green apple | walmart | 23
red apple   | walmart |  5
orange      | macy's  |  4
```

I would want to get all `green apple`s sold in `walmart`, and get the amount of each, for example: 5, 23 ,5.

When using INDEX MATCH, I can only get the first one it matches to. How can I to get multiple values and concatenate them in a single cell?

*Edit* Further example (not added by OP) from comment:

[image: SO17620123 question example]

Comment: Here's an image of what i was hoping to do to give you guys more reference http://uploadpie.com/fpJCJ

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are looking for can be done with worksheet formulas alone. Here is a short VBA routine that should do it.

```
Function MatchConcat(LookupValue, LookupRange As Range, ValueRange As Range)
    Dim lookArr()
    Dim valArr()
    Dim i As Long
    lookArr = LookupRange
    valArr = ValueRange
    For i = 1 To UBound(lookArr)
        If Len(lookArr(i, 1)) <> 0 Then
            If lookArr(i, 1) = LookupValue Then
                MatchConcat = MatchConcat & ", " & valArr(i, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    MatchConcat = Mid(MatchConcat, 3, Len(MatchConcat) - 1)
End Function
```

The code is a user-defined function that can be used in the worksheet. The function takes three arguments:

- the value you want to match,
- the column of values that you want to match against, and
- the column of values that you want to return if there is a match.

It returns a comma-delimited string of the matched values.

The code can be pasted into a standard module (which can be inserted by choosing `Visual Basic` in the `Developer` tab of the ribbon, and then selecting `Insert` -> `Module` from the menu bar.